# JsonConvert.DeseDeserializeObject return null c# in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, api

I have an API request in my web application but every time I convert the response result to deserialize object it gives null value to my model.

Here's my code:

```
var contents = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var statusInfo = responseMessage.StatusCode.ToString();

if (statusInfo == "OK")
{
    var jsonresult = JObject.Parse(contents);
    var respond = jsonresult["data"].ToString();

    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseModel>(respond);
}
```

The contents value is

```
"{\"data\":{\"totalcount:\":8113,\"tpa:\":6107,\"tip:\":5705},\"message\":\"success\"}"
```

The respond value is

```
"{ \r\n"totalcount:\": 8113,\r\n  \"tpa:\": 6107,\r\n  \"tip:\": 5705\r\n}"
```

and my model is

```
public class ResponseModel
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "totalcount")]
    public int totalcount { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "tpa")]
    public int tpa { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "tip")]
    public int tip { get; set; }
}
```

Please help thank you.

Comment: Also you're using `.ToString()` too often. 

Comment: @Oliver I already show the contents result. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have an extra ":" at the end of property name of your json, so try this json property names. This code was tested in Visual Studio and working properly

```
ResponseModel result = null;

if ( responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var json = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var jsonObject = JObject.Parse(json);
        var data=jsonObject["data"];
        if (data!=null) result = data.ToObject<ResponseModel>();
        
    }
 
public class ResponseModel
{
    [JsonProperty("totalcount:")]
    public int totalcount { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("tpa:")]
    public int tpa { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("tip:")]
    public int tip { get; set; }
}
```

or  you can fix an API

Comment: The result variable gives 0 for all properties of model

Comment: @YasSmitch This code was tested in Visual Studio and working properly.  You have to fix all properties of model. BTW "{\"data\" doesn' t have an extra ":", this is why it is working

Answer (score 0):

In my model I added the colon ":" since the return value of the properties in the API has a ":" colon per property.

```
public class ResponseModel
{
   [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "totalcount:")]
   public int totalcount { get; set; }
   [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "tpa:")]
   public int tpa { get; set; }
   [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "tip:")]
   public int tip { get; set; }
}
```